# Filter SharePoint view on basis of URL parameters

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, list-view, view, query-string

I'm developing my site on SharePoint 2013. I've created a view called Advance view. I'm passing 6 parameters to that view in query string(URL).

My requirement is if I pass only 3 parameters in query string then view must be filtered on that 3 parameters only and remaining parameters must not be considered.

Url:
`AdvanceSearch.aspx?pUsr=Chaudhari%20Tushar%20(CSR4XJC)&fromdt=2016-11-13&todt=2016-11-14&status=Assigned&wcd=AT2\AVANIR\002&par=002`

Comment: Are you using query string filter webpart?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I merged two different types of filtering techniques.
For date parameters I used filtering in list view and for remaining parameters I used following technique:

For each field I specified the Filter Field and Filter Value.

&FilterField1=_____&FilterValue1=_____